# Error in query while trying to import data from .dump file

Tags: mysql, data-import

I am trying to import data into MySql table using the query below but the `source` keyword throwing error

```
 SELECT 'LOADING departments' as 'INFO'; *source* load_departments.dump ;
```

`Database` and table `departments` create queries given below:

```
 DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS employees;
 CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS employees;
 USE employees;

 SELECT 'CREATING DATABASE STRUCTURE' as 'INFO';

 CREATE TABLE departments (
  dept_no     CHAR(4)         NOT NULL,
  dept_name   VARCHAR(40)     NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (dept_no),
  UNIQUE  KEY (dept_name)
);
```

Here `departments` is `table` I am trying to import data into and `INFO` is  my `database`.

Comment: How did you create the "load_departments.dump" file?

Comment: @HarryPehkonen I downloaded the dump file.

Comment: What error are you getting?  The dump-file contains INSERT statements?

Comment: @HarryPehkonen yes it contains INSERT statements